# Regular expression not matching the given pattern

Tags: django

```
regular expression not matching.
The current path, attendance/B-2019-07-05, didn't match any of these.
```

from django.urls import path,re_path
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    from . import views as views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('plan/', views.plan_view, name='plan_name'),
    path('journey/', views.Journey_view),
    path('attendance/', views.attendance_view),
    re_path(r'^attendance/(?P<date>\[AB]-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', views.index, name='update_data'),
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login',),
    path('', views.user_logout, name='logout_now'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout_name'),
    path('register/', views.register),
    path('attendance/', views.attendance_view, name='attendance'),  


    path('passwordchange/', views.PasswordChangeView, name='change_password'),
    path('passwordchangedone/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView, name='password_change_done'),
    # path('attendance/', views.attendance_view),  
    re_path(r'^export/csv/$', views.export_report_csv, name='export_report_csv'),
]
```

Comment: What is the backslash in `\[AB` doing here? Can you please share your `urls.py`?

Comment: admin/
plan/ [name='plan_name']
journey/
attendance/
^attendance/(?P<date>\[AB]-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$ [name='update_data']

Comment: That's not the `urls.py` file. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `re_path` contains a backslash:

```
r'^attendance/(?P<date>\[AB]-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$'
#                      ^
```

You should remove this, since by escaping the `[`, you specify that the user should *literally write `[`, so it would accept a URL `attendance/[AB]-2019-07-04/`.

The `re_path` should thus look like:

```
re_path(r'^attendance/(?P<date>[AB]-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', views.index, name='update_data'),
```